# Can't mount a Windows 10 drive for ddrescue

Tags: linux, hard-drive, mount, shutdown, ddrescue

I'm trying to run ddrescue for a drive containing a Windows 10 installation. I have shutdown the operating system with `shutdown /t /s 0` to circumvent the hydrid shutdown issue.

`blkid` shows the partitions of the drive fine and `fdisk` shows the sizes of the partitions too. But I can't mount it, trying to mount it (`mount /dev/sda5 /media/mountpart`) sometimes show a `cant mount special device` error. At other times, mounting is successful but listing the mounted data partition yields a `Input/output error`

`ddrescue` cant read the drive either.

Comment: Just to be sure you're not trying anything wrong: you don't need the source drive being mounted to run `ddrescue`; it shouldn't be mounted with write access while `ddrescue` works nor between `ddrescue` sessions (the content shouldn't change until you have as much of a resulting image as possible). You probably know this. `Input/output error` may be a hardware issue. What does `dmesg` say? If you're using USB bridge, connect the drive directly via SATA interface (if it's SATA; it probably is). Make sure the drive gets enough electrical power for its needs. Any clue in `smartctl -a …` output?